# How do we deploy angular project on IIS with the following proxy config?

Tags: angular, iis, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Following is the part of proxy configuration is used for development

```
 {
   context: "/api/oauth2",
   pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
   target: "https://somedomain.com",
   changeOrigin: true,
   secure: false,
},
```

Actually, we have developed an application using Angular 8.0.
Now we want to deployed on IIS with https SSL enabled.
When we send XHR to this url /api/oauth2 it is not redirected to my dedicated url as proxy configuration is missing on IIS.
How to do same in ARR url rewrite module of IIS?
Or is there any other way to handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Anand Kumar

Answer (score 1):

to work with a reverse proxy in iis you need to install below extensions in iis:

[ARR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module)

[Url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)

enable reverse proxy from the arr. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

add below rule in your site web.configf file:

```
  <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://https://somedomain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```